# I want to allow the user to open my app and mails on WIndows 10

Tags: windows-10

I am writing a winforms/C# application for a windows 10 computer.

I want a "blank" windows desktop: I do not want the user to open recyle bin or explorer. I just want to allow him to launch my app and mail app.

Do you know if it is possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Something like a kiosk?

Comment: no because kiosk only allow 1 app

Comment: You could create an application that would run fullscreen. In that application you could press on two buttons. One for your mail app and another for your app.

Comment: and my app is a very basic C# program which is not on windows store.